# Signing all files correctly published with ClickOnce

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing

We ran into a little bit of trouble while installing our apllication throug ClickOnce.

We own a Verisign Certificate which we use to sign the ClickOnce installer, using the option in VisualStudio. This is working as intended as during the first installation of the application, Windows asks if we are sure to install, but but shows our company as the publisher as intended in the certificate.

However the installed files are not signed. On some of our customer machines, after this first security check, windows throws another warning, regarding the name of the installed apllication-exe, saying the publisher is unknown.

We tried to sign the exe-files in question in the opt-folder throug a postbuld command, which is indeed signing them, but the clickonce installation fails after that, claiming the hash of the file is different from the hash in the manifest.

What is the correct approach to sign ALL exe and dll files in a ClickOnce installaion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a WPF application?  If so, it has a different set of targets and execution order than forms applications, which requires you to use the AfterCompile command rather than the PostBuild command. See RobinDotNet's [blog post](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-revisited/) on this topic for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that very helpfull article. My application is a WindowsForms application and not WPF, but I gave it a shot anyway. Turns out when I do so, the setup.exe is signed and the .exe.deploy file in the ApplicationFiles folder is signed as well. I can deploy the project without breaking the manifest hash, so far so good. Still I get 3(!) security screens on Windows Server 2012. The fist one telling me the identity of the setup is unknown, the other two telling me the correct identity of the setup and the exe file.

Comment: If you are getting Unknown Publisher on the initial install screen, then this indicates that the manifests are not signed with a certificate from a Code Authority.  You need to sign your manifests with the same Verisign certificate that you are using to sign your executables.  As for the 2nd two prompts, those are from the SmartScreen service built into Windows.  Once you gain enough reputation with the SmartScreen service, those will go away.

Comment: We are using the same certificate for the signing of the exe files and the clickonce manifest. The certificate could not be correctly identified because dotnet 4.0 has issues with certificates not using sha1. Updating the target machine to 4.5 resolved that issue. So your answer is indeed correct. Thanks again.